# Splitting Array and adding splitted part to end

Tags: python, arrays

I want to split the array at a point s and add it to the end of the array. But my output is my input list.

```
def split_and_add(arr, s):
    n = len(arr)
    if n >= s or s <=0:
        return arr
    else:
        end = []
        for i in range(0,s):
            end = end + [arr[i]]
        start = []
        for i in range(s,n):
            start = start + [arr[i]]
        return start + end


print(split_and_add([1,2,3,4,5,6],3))
```

The output is still [1,2,3,4,5,6]. Could somebody help?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Expected output: [4,5,6,1,2,3] for d = 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only issue in your code is in line

```py
if n >= s or s <=0:
```

Here, you are checking if length of array `n` is greater than the break point `s` and if yes, you are returning the originl array. But what you need to do is check if `s` is greater than or equal to length of array and if yes, return original array. So, all you need to do is replace `n >= s` with `s >= n`. So your condition would be

```py
if s >= n or s <=0:
    return arr
```

Now, this should work.

Comment: oops :) thanks should have seen something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in a simple way. Just append the left half `arr[:s]` to the right half `arr[s:]` like this.

```
def split_and_add(arr, s):
    n = len(arr)
    if s >= n or s <=0:
        return arr
    return arr[s:] + arr[:s]
```

For the sample input, this gives:

```
split_and_add([1,2,3,4,5,6],3)
 # [4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
```